# Webpack ClosurePlugin - ERROR in closure-compiler: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:>

Tags: webpack, fabricjs, google-closure-compiler

When compiling my bundle file via Webpack ClosurePlugin I get `ERROR in closure-compiler: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 9: ignored C:\Repositories\3dm2\node_modules\fabric\dist`

My config of closure is pretty much the default

```
optimization: {
      minimizer: [
        new ClosurePlugin({mode: 'STANDARD'}, {
          // compiler flags here
          create_source_map: false
          // for debuging help, try these:
          //
          // formatting: 'PRETTY_PRINT'
          // debug: true,
          // renaming: false
        })
      ]
    }
```

I presume some issue in the internal handling of ClosurePlugin with ClosureCompiler - maybe at handover from the Webpack ClosurePlugin to Compiler as some stackoverflow posts refer to the error coming from a wrong way of calling the closure compiler.
Strange thing though. Using the same config for a different project bundle works perfect. So it may also have sth to do with fabric.js which the error refers to.

Using TerserPlugin I have no such issue and the code works perfectly.

So my questions are
1.) Somebody any idea how to resolve this?
2.) Otherwise is there any way to enable some kind of debug log in ClosurePlugin